# Should a migrated question to another SE site, be a part of the News feed at Android-SE?

Tags: discussion, support, feed

Hangout at chat when this appeared:

[image: News feed screen shot]

[The question was migrated to Stackoverflow](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/27619/access-email-configuration-from-own-app), but yet, it was presented at Android Enthusiasts News Feed.

Is it supposed to be? I mean, why something that got off Android would be interesting to Android users?

---

*I noticed that the link still points to Android, perhaps this was presented because the question suffered a status update?*

Comment: No, it shouldn't. But I expect it's just a timing/cache issue. It was probably queued up as part of the feed before it was migrated.